# Trouble with 1st year programming assignment

Tags: java

I'm a first year computer science student having a problem with part of an assignment. The goal of the assignment was to store the coefficients for a polynomial and find its roots using both an array and a linked list. I was able to successfully complete the array version; however the linked list is giving me a headache.

I am able to successfully store the initial round of variables provided in polynomial.java; however, things go a bit crazy once the root calculations begin and the program ends up terminating without giving any roots. I have a feeling this might be being cause by the way the Polynomial.java calculates the roots causing problems with the linked list; however, I am not allowed to change polynomial.java, only LinkedIntList.java. I have been banging my head against the computer for the past 7 hours trying to find the bug and am about ready to just give up on the assignment as I can't reach the professor for help.

I'd greatly appreciate anyone who can spot the bug or are willing to look over the code to provide tips on what I may be doing wrong or how I can work around my problem.

File 1: Node.Java

```
package lists;

public class Node
{
    int element;
    Node next = null;

    /**
     * Constructor which creates a new node containing the value specified by item
     *
    */
    public Node (int item)
    {
        element = item;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the current value of the data item contained inside this node
     */
    public int getElement ()
    {
        return element;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the current value of the data item contained inside this node to
     * the value specified by newVal
     */
    public void setElement (int newVal)
    {
        element = newVal;
    }

    /**
     * Links this node to the node passed in as an argument
     */ 
    public void setNext (Node n)
    {
        next = n;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a reference to the node that follows this node in the
     * linked list, or null if there is no such node
     */
    public Node getNext ()
    {
        return next;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a string based representation of the data item contained
     * in this node.
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        return Integer.toString(element);
    }   
}
```

File 2: LinkedIntList.Java

```
    package lists;

    public class LinkedIntList implements IntList
    {

        Node head = null;
        int count = 0;
        /**
         * Standard Java toString method that returns a string
         * equivalent of the IntList
         *
         * @return  a string indicating the values contained in 
         *          this IntList (ex: "[5 3 2 9 ]")
         */
        public String toString()
        {
            String retVal = "";
            String intermediary = "";
            Node n;
            for (n = head; n.getNext() != null; n = n.getNext())
            {
                intermediary = Integer.toString(n.getElement());
                retVal = intermediary + " " + retVal;
            }
            retVal = n.getElement() + " " + retVal;
            return retVal;
        }

        /**
         * Adds the given value to the <b>end</b> of the list.
         *
         * @param value  the value to add to the list
         */
        public void add (int value)
        {
            Node newNode = new Node (value);

            if (head == null)
                head = newNode;
            else
            {
                Node n = head;
                while (n.getNext() != null)
                {
                    n = n.getNext();
                }
                n.setNext(newNode);
            }
            count++;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the number of elements currently in the list.
         *
         * @return   the number of items currently in the list
         */
        public int size()
        {
            return count;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the element at the specified position in this list.
         *
         * @param index  index of the element to return (zero-based)
         * @return the element at the specified position in this list. 
         * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException  if the index is out of range 
         *                                    (index < 0 || index >= size()). 
         */
        public int get(int index) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
        {
            Node reference = head;
            if (index < 0 || index >= count)
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index out of bounds.");
            }
            for (int i = 0; i != index; i++)
                {
                    reference.getNext();
                }
            return reference.getElement();
        }

        /**
         * Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with 
         * the specified element. 
         *
         * @param index  index of the element to return (zero-based)
         * @param value  element to be stored at the specified position.
         * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException  if the index is out of range 
         *                                    (index < 0 || index >= size()). 
         */
        public void set (int index, int value) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
        {
            if (index < 0 || index >= count)
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index out of bounds.");
            }
            Node newNode = new Node (value);
            Node trailingReference = head;
            Node leadingReference = head.getNext();
                    for(int i = 1; i != index; i++)
                    {
                        trailingReference = leadingReference;
                        leadingReference = leadingReference.getNext();
                    }
            trailingReference.setNext(newNode);
            newNode.setNext(leadingReference);
            count++;
        }
    }
```

File 3: IntList.Java

```
        package lists;

        public interface IntList
        {
            /**
             * Standard Java toString method that returns a string
             * equivalent of the IntList
             *
             * @return  a string indicating the values contained in 
             *          this IntList (ex: "[5 3 2 9 ]")
             */
            public String toString();

            /**
             * Adds the given value to the <b>end</b> of the list.
             *
             * @param value  the value to add to the list
             */
            public void add (int value);

            /**
             * Returns the number of elements currently in the list.
             *
             * @return   the number of items currently in the list
             */
            public int size();

            /**
             * Returns the element at the specified position in this list.
             *
             * @param index  index of the element to return (zero-based)
             * @return the element at the specified position in this list. 
             * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException  if the index is out of range 
             *                                    (index < 0 || index >= size()). 
             */
            public int get(int index);

            /**
             * Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with 
             * the specified element. 
             *
             * @param index  index of the element to return (zero-based)
             * @param value  element to be stored at the specified position.
             * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException  if the index is out of range 
             *                                    (index < 0 || index >= size()). 
             */
            public void set (int index, int value);
        }
```

File 4: Polynomial.java

```
/**
 * A program which finds the integer (whole number) roots of a
 * polynomial with integer coeffecients.  The method used is based
 * upon the ideas presented at:
 *
*/

import lists.*;

public class Polynomial
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        // trick to get out of static context
        new Polynomial().runMe();
    }

    public void runMe()
    {

        IntList poly = new LinkedIntList();

        // Create the polynomial:
        // 3x^10 + 12x^9 - 496x^8 - 211x^7 + 18343x^6 -43760x^5 + 
        //    11766x^4 + 26841x^3 - 126816x^2 + 37278x - 84240
        poly.add (-84240);
        poly.add (37278);
        poly.add (-126816);
        poly.add (26841);
        poly.add (11766);
        poly.add (-43760);
        poly.add (18343);
        poly.add (-211);
        poly.add (-496);
        poly.add (12);
        poly.add (3);

        System.out.print ("Finding the integer roots of the polynomial: ");
        System.out.println (poly);
        IntList roots = findRoots (poly);

        for (int x = 0; x < roots.size(); x++)
            System.out.println ("Root found: " + roots.get(x));
    }

    /**
     * Find all *integer* roots of the polynomial represented by the IntList.
     * 
     * @param poly    a polynomial encoded as a list of coefficients
     * @return     a list of all roots of the given polynomial. Note that
     *         the returned list may have duplicate entries. 
     */
    public IntList findRoots (IntList poly)
    {
        IntList l = new LinkedIntList();  

        int q = poly.get(poly.size() - 1);
        int p = poly.get(0);

        IntList pVals = divTerms(Math.abs(p));
        IntList qVals = divTerms(Math.abs(q));

        IntList possibleZeros = findPotentialZeros(pVals, qVals);

        //for (Integer i : possibleZeros)
        for (int x = 0; x < possibleZeros.size(); x++)
            if (eval (poly, possibleZeros.get(x)) == 0)
                l.add (possibleZeros.get(x));

        return l;
    }

    /**
     * Evaluates the polynomial represented by the IntList with the given
     * value.
     *
     * @param poly    a 
     * @param val    the value to evaluate the polynomial with.
     * @return    f(val), where f is the polynomial encoded as poly
     */
    private int eval (IntList poly, int val)
    {
        int result = 0;
        for (int x = poly.size() - 1; x >= 0; x--)
            result += poly.get(x) * (int) Math.pow (val, x);  

        return result;

    }

    private IntList findPotentialZeros (IntList plist, IntList qlist)
    {

        IntList result = new LinkedIntList();

        for (int p = 0; p < plist.size(); p++)
        {
            for (int q = 0; q < qlist.size(); q++)
            {
                // add it only if q evenly divides p (we're looking
                // for integer roots only
                if (plist.get(p) % qlist.get(q) == 0)
                {
                    int x = plist.get(p) / qlist.get(q);
                    result.add (x);
                    result.add (-x);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }


    /**
     * Find all integers that evenly divide i.
     *
     * @param i    the integer to find all divisors of
     * @return a list of all integers that evenly divide i
     */
    private IntList divTerms (int i)
    {

        IntList v = new LinkedIntList();  


        // 1 divides all numbers
        v.add(1);

        // find all divisors < i and >= 2
        for (int x = 2; x < i; x++)
            if (i % x == 0)
                v.add(x);

        // all numbers are evenly divisible by themselves
        if (i > 1) 
            v.add(i);

        return v;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Aren't you allowed to use java.util.LinkedList?

Comment: @Roman: That would make the assignment too easy wouldn't it?

Comment: @BoltClock: if the subject is Computational Math - then it definitely wouldn't. If the subject is Algorithms and Data Structures - then the part about determining the root of a polinome seems pretty odd to me. If the subject is something like Java Programming - then using java.util.LinkedList should be the preferred way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, the mistake (or one of them) is in your LinkedList imlementation, exactly in `get` method:

```
    public int get(int index) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
    {
        Node reference = head;
        if (index < 0 || index >= count)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index out of bounds.");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i != index; i++)
            {
                reference.getNext(); // <--- the mistake is here
            }
        return reference.getElement();
    }
```

Your `reference` always refers on the head of the list.

If you're allowed to use any java packages - use `java.util.LinkedList`. Otherwise, use java.util.LinkedList until all other parts of your programm would be finished and tested and work as you wish. After that carefully replace it with your LinkedList implementation.

Comment: Yup, I forgot to make reference = reference.getNext();

Answer (score 0):

The `set` method in the `LinkedIntList` isn't adhering to the contract specified in the Javadoc. It says replace the element at the given index but I see code that adds a new `Node`.

Have a look at what methods the `Node` class provides to help you make the `set` method a lot easier and correct.

Comment: Well that's what I get for recycling my code without paying attention. I guess I was a little tired when I first added that method and copied a remove one instead of creating a set one.

Answer (score 0):

Take a good look at your get implementation. It does not do what you think.